# How do you password protect excel VBA macro from running

Tags: excel, vba

I have just finished writing my code and have added a button to the sheet. I am hoping there is a way to protect the button from "miss use" as it is only meant for one person only.

Comment: Why not put a check like `If user=someonespecial Then executecode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environment variables to check for your special user: `Environ$("computername")` if you want to check by computer or `Environ$("username")` if you are rather interested in Login username. (Or use both for one user in one computer).

Then for extra security password protect your VBA code.

EDIT:

I have just realised that I didn't answer the question. (Or I answered what I wanted).
If you want to protect by password your macro, one solution is making your button call a userform with a `TextBox1` and a `CommandButton1`.

Then the code in the UserForm should look:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If TextBox1.Value = "Password" Then 'Replace Password by your custom password
        LaunchYourMacro 'This is the sub that was being called by your button.
    Else
        MsgBox "You are not allowed to launch the macro"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Hope one solution or the other is helpful.

Comment: that is fantastic. One one more question is, do you put that before the main body of the code or after? as I am getting a `Sub or function not defined`

Comment: You need to insert a UserForm with a TextBox and Button. (If you get lost here you can check: http://www.homeandlearn.org/getting_started_with_user_forms.html). Then Right click your userform, click code and paste the code above. Let me know how do you get on.

Comment: thanks for this, I will have to give it a go later as I am getting a bit lost, full day of coding and my head is about to explode.