# Compile error: Expected End Sub

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a macro assigned to a shape and want to password protect this macro so that when the shape is clicked a pop-up box appears asking for a passwork, and ideally I want to do this through a User Form.

I have looked at this question: [How do you password protect excel VBA macro from running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384321/how-do-you-password-protect-excel-vba-macro-from-running) and have done what I believe the answerer is saying, so my code is as follows:

```
Sub EmailExtract()

UserForm1.Show

***Code for the macro then follows***

End Sub
```

And then the User Form for clicking the button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "Password" Then 'Replace Password by your custom password
    Sub EmailExtract() 'This is the sub that was being called by your button.
Else
    MsgBox "You are not allowed to launch the macro"
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

But when I try to run this I get the error `Compile error: Expected End Sub` on the line: `If TextBox1.Value = "Password" Then`

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you have to close the `If statement` with `End If` After `Exit Sub`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've just tried that and I'm still getting the error

Comment: don't you have an infinite loop? you click the button on the user form -> start sub `emailextract` -> open the userform we had two steps before

Comment: That's a good shout, I didn't see that, apart from adding in another macro to start the user form is there a way of getting round that?

Comment: Get rid of `Sub`! It doesn't belong there. Replace `Sub EmailExtract()` with `EmailExtract`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have to close the `If statement` with `End If` After `Exit Sub`
- And you are calling a `Sub` within a `Sub` which throws the `End Sub error` you only need to put in `EmailExtract`

See code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "Password" Then 'Replace Password by your custom password
    EmailExtract 'This is the sub that was being called by your button.
Else
    MsgBox "You are not allowed to launch the macro"
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

**Update:**

This is a different approach on password protection and simply uses an `InputBox` instead of an `UserForm` to collect and check a password value.

Make sure that you password protect your VBA code, otherwise anyone that knows how can check the code and get the password from the code.

```
Sub EmailExtract()
Dim Message As String, Title As String, Password As String
Message = "Enter the macro password"    ' Set prompt.
Title = "Macro Password"    ' Set title.
Password = InputBox(Message, Title)
If Password = "Password Here" Then

    ''***Code for the macro then follows***

Else
    MsgBox "You are not allowed to launch the macro"
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

**2nd Update:**

This way you create a `Sub` to call the `UserForm` then validate the password input, after that you call the `sub EmailExtract()` and run the desired code.

The way for using a password protection with a `UserForm` is as followed:

Show `UserForm` (being called by your shape):

```
Sub UserFormShow()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Do password validation:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "Password" Then 'Replace Password by your custom password
    EmailExtract 'The new sub your going to call
Else
    MsgBox "You are not allowed to launch the macro"
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Run your code (the new sub):

```
Sub EmailExtract()

***Code for the macro then follows***

end sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked brilliantly! The only error I'm getting now, which I think relates to  what @psychicebola pointed out in a comment, is when the password is entered the error: `Run-time error 400: Form already displayed; can't show modally` appears, is there a way I can use the User Form and call it within the macro without there being the loop?

Comment: so when the shape is clicked it runs a macro which calls the userform where you then need to enter a password correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, so it goes click button > starts macro > opens user form > if password is correct go back to the macro

Comment: so the macro opens the UserForm to collect the password checks it and if correct goes back to the macro. why then do you use EmailExtract to call the UserForm. i will edit my anwser to give a more simple option instead of an UserForm

Comment: Thank you for the edit, that works fine! Is it not at all possible to use a user form then?

Comment: It is possible if you would really like to I could add the proper code for that too. But its for what you want much more logical (imo) to use an `InputBox` instead of creating a complete `UserForm`.

Comment: I would like to see how I could do it in a `User Form` if that is possible as this is something I'd like to take further elsewhere